# Add div before the div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<p></p>    
<div class="comment_like">
    <span class="reaction_2 tooltipstered" id="like13seperator2" rel="unlike"><i 
    class="likeIconDefault"></i>Like</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to add this div:   `<div class="commentLikeCount"></div>` before this `comment_like` class using jQuery.

I am trying with this code:

```
$("#like"+posts_id).parents(".comment_like").prepend('<div class="commentLikeCount"></div>');
```

but somehow not working :(

**Updated for the new Questions:**

Now I have that HTML:

```
<p></p>
<div class="commentLikeCount">
    <br>
    <span class="float-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;1</span>
    <img src="assets/images/db_haha.png" alt="" class="float-right old">
    <img src="assets/images/db_love.png" alt="" class="float-right">
</div>

<div class="comment_like">
    <span class="unLike_2" id="like13seperator2" rel="unlike">
        <i class="loveIconSmall likeTypeSmall"></i>Love
    </span>
</div>
```

Now, I just want to remove the last Img from the `coomentLikeCount` class.

Comment: Oh, I think I need to use `before()`  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```
$('<div class="commentLikeCount" />')
.insertBefore($("#like"+posts_id).parents(".comment_like"))
```

Or [before](http://api.jquery.com/before):

```
$("#like"+posts_id).parents(".comment_like")
.before('<div class="commentLikeCount" />')
```

If you're inserting `commentLikeCount` in every `.comment_like`, then just use `$('.comment_like')` instead of `$("#like"+posts_id).parents(".comment_like")`

Regarding your comment:

> well if I already have this div  then how can select this div?

You can prepend using insertBefore like:

```
$('.commentLikeComment').insertBefore($("#like"+posts_id).parents(".comment_like"));
```

To your updated question, you can remove last image like:

```
$('.commentLikeCount img').last().remove()
```

Comment: well if I  already have this div `<div class="commentLikeCount"></div>` then how can select this div?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Please check my updated questions: can use your updated code to get this?

Comment: should I use this also `$("#like"+posts_id)` ?

Comment: Yeah, if that's specific.

Comment: I am Sorry :( I forget to tell you that all of this HTML has a parent class called `all_comments` so I am using this: `$("#like"+posts_id).parents(".all_comments").find(".commentLikeCount img").last().remove();`

Comment: Mya be I found it using this code: `$("#like"+posts_id).parents(".all_comments").find(".commentLikeCount").find("img:last-child").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `before()`.

`$(".comment_like").before("<div class='commentLikeCount'></div>");`